# Update columns in one data frame with values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update `df2` with columns and data in `ref_df1` such that my output data frame has all columns `['Code', 'Place', 'Product', 'Name', 'Value']` and has pulled data from the reference data frame using `Code` column values as key. I am not sure how to get to the output.

```py
import pandas as pd


data1 = {
    'Code': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Name': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3', 'Company4', 'Company5', 'Company6'],
    'Value': [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700],
}

ref_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Code', 'Name', 'Value'])
    
data2 = {
    'Code': [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6],
    'Place': ['A', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'L'],
    'Product': ['P11', 'P22', 'P12', 'P33', 'P44', 'P13', 'P61'],
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Code', 'Place', 'Product'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Look up `pd.merge`

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` both the data frames.

```py
df2.merge(ref_df1)
#output:
   Code Place Product      Name  Value
0     1     A     P11  Company1    200
1     1     E     P12  Company1    200
2     1     K     P13  Company1    200
3     2     B     P22  Company2    300
4     3     G     P33  Company3    400
5     4     I     P44  Company4    500
6     6     L     P61  Company6    700
```

Comment: In the actual dataset this operation appears to remove some rows and repeat others. Would you know some common reasons on why that could happen?

Comment: If it is removing the rows, that means `ref_df1` doesn't have value for all the `Code` that are in your `df2`, if you see repeated rows, it means your actual dataset itself has the repeated rows.

Comment: I think that should be a left merge based on the expected output. `df2.merge(ref_df1, how='left')`